# how make using of my web api to improve alexa rank of my website?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api, google-analytics-api, alexa-rank

I have a webservice (asp.net web api2), and I use it in qt quick application for android and a winform application.
I want to know if my users use these applications.

1. Is this using have affect on alexa rank of my web site?
2. How should I improve alexa rank with use of  webservice?

Comment: No, it won't show up in Alexa ranking at all. Add some analytics, or analyze your server logs.

Answer (score 2):

Alexa rank is *purely* measuring the rank, according to the number of people visited your website and who have the Alexa toolbar (or any other SEO toolbar with Alexa rank tracker) installed.

> APIs and other things have zero direct affect on how you rank in
>   Alexa.